# How to expand a single bit to multi-bits depending on parameter in verilog?

Tags: verilog

For example, I have an input `wire fx`, and `parameter DATAWIDTH`.

Can I write

```
wire [DATAWIDTH - 1 : 0] exfx;
assign exfx = {(DATAWIDTH - 1){1'b0}, fx};
```

to zero expand the signal fx to DATAWIDTH?

What if I want (DATAWIDTH - 1) bits 1? or more complex combination?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are nearly there.

`assign exfx = {{(DATAWIDTH-1){1'b0}}, fx};`

This part: `{(DATAWIDTH-1){1'b0}}` are your extra zeros.
Then you add those to fx using the { ... } operator.

This is 8 zero bits: `{8{1'b0}}`.
This is also 8 bits but the pattern 01010101    : `{4{2'b01}}`

The count can be an expression: `{2*DATAWIDTH-1{1'b0}}`

You can also use that to sign-extend a number by repeating the MS bit:

```
localparam WIDTH = 16;
wire       [7:0] A;
wire [WIDTH-1:0] B; 

// Works only for WIDTH > 8 !!
assign B = { {WIDTH-8{A[7]}} , A };
```

Comment: I removed the section that the expression must be between brackets. I always automatically do that but it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. However, your `exfx` is of DATAWIDTH+1 size currently

A simple assign also works -

`assign exfx = fx;`

It will assign `fx` value to LSB and will have `0`s in the rest

Comment: What if I want (DATAWIDTH - 1) bits 1? or more complex combination?